# Python 3.8 - Package release broken, but works when installed locally

Tags: python, pip, packaging

Okay, so I'm developing this python package that we release on Pypi and Anaconda. In it, we have a number of python files containing classes. Historically, I've used the following structure, without issue.

```
repo/
    conda/
        conda_build_config.yaml
        meta.yaml
    setup.py
    src/
        A
            ClassA
        B
            ClassB
        ...
        __init__.py
            from .A import ClassA
            from .B import ClassB
            ...
```

We do GitHub releases, and GitHub actions bundles everything up for us and publishes to PyPi and Condas. Pretty simple. But the number of classes has grown to the point where a flat hierarchy doesn't really make sense, and we want to start grouping them into subpackages nested in individual groups, like so:

```
repo/
    conda/
        conda_build_config.yaml
        meta.yaml
    setup.py
    package/
        Group1/
            A
                ClassA
            B
                ClassB
            __init__.py
                from .A import ClassA
                from .B import ClassB
        Group2/
            C
                ClassC
            D
                ClassD
            __init__.py
                from .C import ClassC
                from .D import ClassD
        ...
        __init__.py
            from .Group1 import ClassA
            from .Group1 import ClassB
            from .Group2 import ClassA
            from .Group2 import ClassB
            ...
```

Here's the weird thing: if I run `pip install -e .` to test it locally, this new setup works exactly how I want it to. But, if I release it to PyPi, `pip install package`, and then run `import package`, I get the following error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named package.A`

I've tried several different organizational structures, using **init**.py in various ways, and all of the suggestions and structures I've found from other related questions, but it seems invariably that, what works as a local install doesn't work when pushed to PyPi. What am I missing here?

---Edit---

In addition to the solution described in the accepted answer, I had to move my `package/` into a `src/` and add the following to my `setup.py`:

```
package_dir={"": "src"},
packages=find_packages(where="src"),
```

This made sure that all the subpackages got bundled into the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to add the `__all__` variable in your `__init__.py` files.
For example in the `__init__.py` from `Group1`, we can add :

```py
from .A import ClassA
from .B import ClassB

__all__ = [
    'ClassA',
    'ClassB'
]
```

And apply the same trick to the other `__init__.py` from the other folders.
This should do the job.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! Can't believe I couldn't find that anywhere else.

Comment: I agree with you, the first time was really hard to find it for me too. Happy to help you !